# Cant't launch jupyter notebook due to could not decode path

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I use anaconda to install jupyter
Following is my command

$ `activate demo`      ....demo is my environment name

$ `conda install jupyter`

$ `jupyter notebook`

and then it will get following error message

> [C 10:39:17.591 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
>
> [C 10:39:17.594 NotebookApp] Could not decode 'C:\Users\\xbeG\xa8|\xa5\xe0\.jupyter' for unicode trait 'config_dir' of a NotebookApp instance.

I think my path under `C:` has chinese, so it can't decode properly.
I also see some similar issue https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5345

but this solution is no help to me, because I use window, I also tried to use
`chcp` in CMD to change language. It doesn't work too.( I have tried `chcp950` ,`chcp65001`,`chcp436`)

Are there anyone have idea about my problem?

I also have another problem is that when I `conda install jupyter` , it seems
to be installed in `C:` automatically, I want to know are there any method install it to specific path? If it can achieve, I think there is no decode problem because path under `D:` didn't have chinese.

Thanks all of your help.

my environment:

`Python 3.6.5`

`conda 4.6.11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it'll fix your problem but you can install conda packages to a different directory by creating a different environment.

```
conda create --prefix D:\my_conda python=3.7
activate D:\my_conda
```

I think you can create `.condarc` file inside the root of this new conda environment and it'll override the one in your home directory.

Comment: should I add `.condarc` one layer under `myconda` ? After I finish your command, there is empty in `.condarc`. Is it right?

Comment: Another question, if I create new environment in other folder under `D:`, it will automatically reference it to `myconda` under `D:` if I install something like jupyter ?

Comment: Yes, create a the config file here: `D:\my_conda\.condarc` if you need to overwrite any settings normally in `%userprofile%\.condarc` (I believe). Yes, it'll automatically reference the jupyter in your new conda environment assuming it's the active one.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you just save me a day! But I think your answer only work when it is under `D:\my_conda` instead of any folder under `D:`

Comment: But I still very appreciate your helpful answer !